# Как спрятать мобильное меню после выбора пункта?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Код мобильного меню(Пункты в меню якори). На данный момент после нажатия на пункт меню, скролл происходит, а меню не закрывается.

```
<div class="header__nav-wrap">
                            <div class="header__nav-close"></div>
                            <ul class="header__nav">
                                <?php
                                wp_nav_menu(
                                    array(
                                        'theme_location'  => 'header_menu',
                                        'menu'            => '',
                                        'container'       => false,
                                        'container_id'    => '',
                                        'menu_class'      => 'menu',
                                        'menu_id'         => 'nav-main',
                                        'echo'            => true,
                                        'fallback_cb'     => '__return_empty_string',
                                        'before'          => '',
                                        'after'           => '',
                                        'link_before'     => '',
                                        'link_after'      => '',
                                        'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
                                        'depth'           => 0
                                    )
                                );?>
                                <li class="header__nav-number">
                                 <a href="tel:"></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Comment: `php` тут не сильно нужен. Добавьте готовую разметку и `js`-код для мобильного меню и прокрутки по якорям.

Comment: @zhurof я бы и хотел посмотреть какие-то решения. Может кто-то уже делал.

Comment: Чтобы закрыть ваше меню, надо знать как оно открывается  и что происходит при клике по его ссылкам.

Answer (score 0):

```js
;(function (){
  const nav = document.querySelector(".header__nav");
  nav.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
    nav.setAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden");
  });
})();
```

```html
<div class="header__nav-wrap">
                            <div class="header__nav-close"></div>
                            <ul class="header__nav">
                                <!-- <?php
                                wp_nav_menu(
                                    array(
                                        'theme_location'  => 'header_menu',
                                        'menu'            => '',
                                        'container'       => false,
                                        'container_id'    => '',
                                        'menu_class'      => 'menu',
                                        'menu_id'         => 'nav-main',
                                        'echo'            => true,
                                        'fallback_cb'     => '__return_empty_string',
                                        'before'          => '',
                                        'after'           => '',
                                        'link_before'     => '',
                                        'link_after'      => '',
                                        'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
                                        'depth'           => 0
                                    )
                                );?>-->
                                <li class="header__nav-number">
                                 <a href="tel:"></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Вот тут примерное решение вашей проблемы:

- вешаем обработчик на клик по вашему меню;
- при клике меняем видимость ел-та ul на hidden, способ скрытия возможно вам не подойдет  - используйте тот способ что предусмотрен в вордпресе (возможно это назначения спец.класа для сокрытия ел-та, я по вордпресу не силен);
- меню скроется